# Keeping track of number of characters removed in strings, python `strip()`

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, strip

I have a pair of strings. In this case, let's think of them as two separate strings assigned to unique variables. These strings have equal length:

```
var1 = 'AnAppleADayKeepsTheDoctorAway'
var2 = '000Ig00000noranceIsBliss00000'
```

The most efficient way I know to strip beginning and trailing characters from a string in Python is the method `strip()`:

```
print(var2.strip('0'))
'Ig00000noranceIsBliss'
```

I would like to remove the same number of character from the string `var1`, as they are a "pair". In this case, that would be remove the first three characters and the trailing five characters, i.e.

```
'ppleADayKeepsTheDocto'
```

Is there a method which allows me to efficiently strip characters like in `var1` and then keep track of the number of these characters to do the same for the second string,`var2`? I'm not sure `strip()` would be the best method for this task.

EDIT: Obviously, there's a solution.

e.g.

```
length_original = len(var2)
num_left_chars = len(var2) - len(var2.lstrip('0'))
num_right_chars = len(var2.rstrip('0'))
edited = var1[num_left_chars:num_right_chars]
print(edited)
## printed
## 'ppleADayKeepsTheDocto'
```

I'm looking for an *efficient* solution. If there a quicker Pythonic method?

Comment: How would you solve this (by hand, forget about Python for a while)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have the basic solution above. Please see edit. I should clarify that I'm searching for an efficient solution, as I will need to iterate over millions of "paired strings" with this.

Comment: Just to be sure: do you really only need to strip, or should the `00000` in the middle of `000Ig00000noranceIsBliss00000` also be deleted together with the according part of `AnAppleADayKeepsTheDoctorAway`?

Comment: @SpghttCd The `00000` in the middle should stay

Comment: I'm happy to delete this question. I think my motivation wasn't clear---I realize how to solve this, as the edit shows. However, when iterating over millions of "pairs" of such strings, there might be more efficient methods than initiating values each time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it in two steps: first, strip the front, and then strip the back. Then you can count how many characters were stripped on each side, and use string slicing. You can use `lstrip()` and `rstrip()` for this. Example:

```
var1 = 'AnAppleADayKeepsTheDoctorAway'
var2 = '000Ig00000noranceIsBliss00000'

num_leading = len(var2) - len(var2.lstrip('0'))
num_trailing = len(var2) - len(var2.rstrip('0'))

print(var2.strip())
print(var1[num_leading:-1*num_trailing])
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that there is no such method. So for your problem, you would want to find the difference between the length of the old & new value of var 2 as such:

```
var1 = 'AnAppleADayKeepsTheDoctorAway'
var2 = '000Ig00000noranceIsBliss00000'
old_length = len(var2)
var2 = var2.strip('0')
diff_length = old_length - len(var2)
var1 = var1[diff_length:len(var1)-diff_length]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lstrip(..)` and `rstrip(..)` separately, and each time count the number of characters that were removed, and slice with these characters:

```
var1 = 'AnAppleADayKeepsTheDoctorAway'
var2 = '000Ig00000noranceIsBliss00000'

n0 = len(var2)
var3 = var2.lstrip('0')
nl = n0 - len(var3)

var2s = var3.rstrip('0')

var1s = var1[nl:len(var2s)+nl]
```

So we slice `var1s` in such way that we remove `nl` leading characters (the number of characters we removed with `lstrip(..)`), and then we ensure that the length is the same as the number of characters in `var2s` (`var2` after both `lstrip(..)` and `rstrip(..)`).

We thus then obtain:

```
>>> var1s
'ppleADayKeepsTheDocto'
>>> var2s
'Ig00000noranceIsBliss'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create index slices using the change in lengths after stripping either side

```
left = var2.lstrip('0')
start = len(var2) - len(left)

right = var2.rstrip('0')
end = (len(var2) - len(right))

var1 = var1[start: len(var1) - end]
var2 = var2.strip('0')
```

> ```
> ppleADayKeepsTheDocto 
> Ig00000noranceIsBliss
> ```